# how to dispose of scoped region mangers in PRISM

Tags: wpf, prism

I am creating a scoped region manager to handle dialog windows but I couldn't find any information if you have to clean-up scope region mangers once you are finished with them.

There are not any close or dispose methods that I could find so are they just handled by the garbage collector once out of scope or are you meant to remove the view from it first?

```
   public void ShowDialog(string region, string module, NavigationParameters navigationParameters, WindowPosition windowPosition, bool modal = true)
    {
        var dialog = _container.Resolve<DialogShellView>();

        //use a scoped region just in case you can have multiple instances
        var scopedRegion = _regionManager.CreateRegionManager();
        //set the region manager of the dialog to the scoped region
        RegionManager.SetRegionManager(dialog, scopedRegion);
        //navigate to show the desired view in the dialog
        scopedRegion.RequestNavigate(region, module, navigationParameters);
        //Set dialog position
        dialog.Top = windowPosition.Top;
        dialog.Left = windowPosition.Left;

        if (modal)
        {
            //show the dialog
            dialog.ShowDialog();
            scopedRegion.Regions.Remove(region);
        }
        else
        {
            dialog.Closed += (sender, e) => OnFinishEvent(sender, e, region, scopedRegion, dialog);
            dialog.Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be useful to know why the neg votes were given so I could then improve the question